# Print to .pdf printer creates corrupted file

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, corruption, printdocument

Trying to print to file and create a .pdf from .docx or .xlsx

It manages to create the file, but when trying to open it, says the file is damaged or corrupted.

Code:

```
        string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);

        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.DocumentName = filename;

        PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        printerSettings.PrinterName = "PDFCreator";
        //printerSettings.PrinterName = "CutePDF Writer";

        printerSettings.PrintToFile = true;
        printerSettings.PrintFileName = String.Format(@"{0}/{1}.pdf", path, name);

        pd.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
        pd.Print();
```

Looking at the PDF in the text editor, the header reads:

> %!PS-Adobe-3.0
>   %%Title: C:\Junk\Sample.docx
>   %%Creator: PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2
>   %%CreationDate: 2/24/2017 14:12:57
>   %%For: user
>   %%BoundingBox: (atend)
>   %%Pages: (atend)
>   %%Orientation: Portrait
>   %%PageOrder: Special
>   %%DocumentNeededResources: (atend)
>   %%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
>   %%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
>   %%TargetDevice: (PDFCreator) (3010) 096
>   %%LanguageLevel: 3
>   %%EndComments
>   %%BeginDefaults
>   %%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
>   %%ViewingOrientation: 1 0 0 1
>   %%EndDefaults

Have tried editing the header to variations of %PDF for the first line, but so far nothing has made the file openable.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Printing to a file is not the same as specifying the location to save the file generated by a PDF printer; it simply outputs all of the instructions that would normally be sent to the printer to a file instead (in this case, a series of PostScript commands). There is no way to programmatically specify where the PDF printer should save the file it generates, as this is implementation-specific.

Comment: This answer is true for PDFCreator and CutePDF Writer, but it isn't true for all PDF printers.  Some PDF printers such as Win2PDF output to PDF directly and do support the .NET .PrintToFileName and .PrintFileName properties.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Bradley and Craig. I'll attempt Win2PDF, and if it still doesn't work I'll go back to opening an instance of Word.